# Commit clear interrupted state

Tags: android, multithreading, sharedpreferences, interrupt

In the application I'm developing, I have a thread that is running in a loop. Inside the loop, several conditions are evaluated, and depends on these conditions, a value or another is stored in the SharedPreferences.

```
public void run()
{
  try
  {
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
       context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    while (true)
    {                       
      if (condition1)
      {
        editor.putBoolean("mykey", "1");
      }
      else if (condition 2)
      {
        editor.putBoolean("mykey", "2");            
      }
      editor.commit();

      if (isInterrupted())
         throw new InterruptedException();              

      Thread.sleep(60000); // 60 seconds
    }
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e)
  {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```

This thread is started by an Activity in the onResume method, and is interrupted in the onPause method.

If the thread is interrupted by the activity (main thread) when it is sleeping, an InterruptedException is thrown. That is ok.

But my problem is that if the activity (main thread) interrupts the thread when it is running (and not sleeping). The "interrupted flag" is set to true, but after calling commit on the editor, the flag is set to false, so I can't interrupt the thread throwing an InterruptedException.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `editor.commit()` is going to do I/O. If there is a pending interrupt on the thread then this will likely abort the I/O and clear the pending interrupt.

In order to do what you want you will probably need to prevent that the thread is interrupted while committing. You'll need to synchronize the access so that the application can only interrupt it while the thread is sleeping. Something like this:

```
// This method will interrupt the thread that is looping ONLY while it is sleeping
public synchronized void interruptNow() {
    threadThatIsLooping.interrupt();
}

public void run() {
try {
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
       context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    while (true) {
        synchronized {
            // Cannot be interrupted within this block                  
            if (condition1) {
                editor.putBoolean("mykey", "1");
            } else if (condition 2) {
                editor.putBoolean("mykey", "2");            
            }
            editor.commit();
        }             
        Thread.sleep(60000); // 60 seconds
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Do whatever you want here when the thread is interrupted while sleeping
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll do what you say. What I don't understand is why "editor.commit" don't throw a InterruptedException instead of clearing the pending interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran over the same issue and found the solution.

You might use [editor.apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29) instead of [editor.commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29)!

The reason why apply() works instead of commit(), is that it does the I/O on a new thread because it doesn't need to wait for the return value:

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
>   this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
>   still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
>   completed as well as the commit itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't do this: `while (true)`

Secondly, if the thread is interrupted:

```
if (isInterrupted())
         throw new InterruptedException();              

      Thread.sleep(60000); // 60 seconds
    }
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e)
  {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
```

It catches the interruption and then interrupts the thread again.  This screams recursion, and your infinite while loop isn't helping things.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that I should not do "while (true)". When in the InterruptedException catch block I interrupt the thread again is because I must do it. Please read the section "Don't swallow interrupts" of the next article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: It is very bad programming practice to include any infinite loops.  This loop will never truly end and will eat up battery and processing power.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that a infinite loop is not a good practice, but in the infinite loop I've writen I have a call to a sleep method, so most of the time the thread is sleeping. In the other hand, the thread is not always running, it is interrumpted by other thread.

Comment: Anyway, what I don't undestand is why the commit method clears the "interrupted flag" of the thread.

Comment: Have you tried putting the check for interruption before you handle the editor object?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm not very sure where you say to put the check for interrumption.

Comment: put if (isInterrupted())
         throw new InterruptedException();  

before if(condition1)

Comment: Thanks but this not solve my problem. If the thread is interrupted just between "if(condition1)" and "commit", I've the same problem. When the main thread call "interrupt", the "interrupted flag" is put to true. But when the other thread call "commit", the "interrupted flag" is clear